# Python Text Summarizer - maintain sentence order

Tags: python, nlp

I am teaching myself python and have completed a rudimentary text summarizer. I'm nearly happy with the summarized text but want to polish the final product a bit more.

The code performs some standard text processing correctly (tokenization, remove stopwords, etc). The code then scores each sentence based on a weighted word frequency. I am using the heapq.nlargest() method to return the top 7 sentences which I feel does a good job based on my sample text.

The issue I'm facing is that the top 7 sentences are returned sorted from highest score -> lowest score. I understand the *why* this is happening. I would prefer to maintain the same sentence order as present in the original text. I've included the relevant bits of code and hope someone can guide me on a solution.

```
#remove all stopwords from text, build clean list of lower case words
clean_data = []
for word in tokens:
    if str(word).lower() not in stoplist:
        clean_data.append(word.lower())

#build dictionary of all words with frequency counts: {key:value = word:count}
word_frequencies = {}
for word in clean_data:
    if word not in word_frequencies.keys():
        word_frequencies[word] = 1
    else:
        word_frequencies[word] += 1

#print(word_frequencies.items())

#update the dictionary with a weighted frequency 
maximum_frequency = max(word_frequencies.values())
#print(maximum_frequency)

for word in word_frequencies.keys():
    word_frequencies[word] = (word_frequencies[word]/maximum_frequency)

#print(word_frequencies.items())

#iterate through each sentence and combine the weighted score of the underlying word
sentence_scores = {}

for sent in sentence_list:
    for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent.lower()):
        if word in word_frequencies.keys():
            if len(sent.split(' ')) < 30:
                if sent not in sentence_scores.keys():
                    sentence_scores[sent] = word_frequencies[word]
                else:
                    sentence_scores[sent] += word_frequencies[word]

#print(sentence_scores.items())                    

summary_sentences = heapq.nlargest(7, sentence_scores, key = sentence_scores.get)

summary = ' '.join(summary_sentences)    

print(summary)
```

I'm testing using the following article: https://www.bbc.com/news/world-australia-45674716

Current output: "Australia bank inquiry: 'They didn't care who they hurt'
The inquiry has also heard testimony about corporate fraud, bribery rings at banks, actions to deceive regulators and reckless practices. A royal commission this year, the country's highest form of public inquiry, has exposed widespread wrongdoing in the industry. The royal commission came after a decade of scandalous behaviour in Australia's financial sector, the country's largest industry. "[The report] shines a very bright light on the poor behaviour of our financial sector," Treasurer Josh Frydenberg said. "When misconduct was revealed, it either went unpunished or the consequences did not meet the seriousness of what had been done," he said. The bank customers who lost everything
He also criticised what he called the inadequate actions of regulators for the banks and financial firms. It has also received more than 9,300 submissions of alleged misconduct by banks, financial advisers, pension funds and insurance companies."

As an example of the desired output: The third sentence above, "A royal commission this year, the country's highest form of public inquiry, has exposed widespread wrongdoing in the industry." actually comes before "Australia bank inquiry: They didnt care who they hurt" in the original article and I would like the output to maintain that sentence order.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working, leaving here in case others are curious:

```
#iterate through each sentence and combine the weighted score of the underlying word
sentence_scores = {}
cnt = 0
for sent in sentence_list:
    sentence_scores[sent] = []
    score = 0
    for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent.lower()):
        if word in word_frequencies.keys():
            if len(sent.split(' ')) < 30:
                if sent not in sentence_scores.keys():
                    score = word_frequencies[word]
                else:
                    score += word_frequencies[word]
    sentence_scores[sent].append(score)
    sentence_scores[sent].append(cnt)
    cnt = cnt + 1


#Sort the dictionary using the score in descending order and then index in ascending order
#Getting the top 7 sentences
#Putting them in 1 string variable
from operator import itemgetter
top7 = dict(sorted(sentence_scores.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse = True)[0:7])
#print(top7)
def Sort(sub_li):
    return(sorted(sub_li, key = lambda sub_li: sub_li[1])) 
sentence_summary = Sort(top7.values())
summary = ""
for value in sentence_summary:
    for key in top7:
        if top7[key] == value:
            summary = summary + key
print(summary)
```